# Display eclipse output in external window

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have started to use eclipse for my C++ projects. When I run the application(using run button), I can see the output in console in the IDE, but I want to see the output in a popped up external terminal-style window. I have seen this happening in one of the youtube videos for eclipse. I have researched but couldnt find the steps to do this. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the console tab and click "detached".

Also, this has already been answered here I think: [Eclipse open console apps in separate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888599/eclipse-open-console-apps-in-separate-window)